# Placing text into stacked bar charts in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have difficulty placing text into the correct positions of a stacked barplot. Specifically, I want to place the `ZipfColl_mean` values into the middle of their respective stacks:

```
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)

adj %>%
  group_by(Struktur2) %>%
  mutate(ZipfColl_mean = round(mean(ZipfColl),2)) %>%
  
ggplot(aes(fill=Struktur2, x=Adjektivsemantik))+ 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "count") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T, option = "E", name = "Structure", labels = c("full", "fragment", "topic drop")) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Adjektivsemantik, y = ZipfColl_mean, label = ZipfColl_mean, color = "red"))+
  ggtitle("") +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Feedbackposition), cols=vars(Referenzstruktur), switch="y") +
  theme_ipsum() +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

How can the `ZipfColl_mean` values be placed **into the middle** of their respective stacks?

Data:

```
adj <- structure(list(Struktur2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("full", 
                                                                                                                 "fragment", "topic_drop"), class = "factor"), Adjektivsemantik = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("descriptive", "evaluative"), class = "factor"), 
                     Referenzstruktur = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("individual", 
                                                                                                                    "proposition"), class = "factor"), Feedbackposition = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("other", "feedback"), class = "factor"), 
                     ZipfColl = c(4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 
                                  4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 5.61, 5.61, 5.61, 5.61, 5.61, 5.61, 5.61, 
                                  5.61, 5.61)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                                              14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach which computes the counts outside of `ggplot()` uses the counts for `y` position of the labels too as well as `position = position_stack(vjust = .5)`:

```r
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

adj %>%
  mutate(ZipfColl_mean = round(mean(ZipfColl), 2), .by = Struktur2) |>
  summarise(
    ZipfColl_mean = unique(ZipfColl_mean),
    count = n(),
    .by = c(Feedbackposition, Adjektivsemantik, Referenzstruktur, Struktur2)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Adjektivsemantik, count, fill = Struktur2)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_viridis(
    discrete = T, option = "E", name = "Structure",
    labels = c("full", "fragment", "topic drop")
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = Adjektivsemantik, y = count,
      label = ZipfColl_mean,
      color = "ZipfColl_mean"
    ),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5),
    key_glyph = "point"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "red", labels = NULL) +
  facet_grid(
    rows = vars(Feedbackposition),
    cols = vars(Referenzstruktur), switch = "y"
  ) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  labs(x = NULL, title = NULL, color = "ZipfColl_mean")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! How can I add a legend title for "ZipfColl_mean"?

Comment: Aw. Sorry. I thought you have put `color="red"` accidentally inside `aes()`. Just fixed it and used `scale_color_manual` to get a true "red".

Comment: Can we get rid of the letter "a"? Just replace it by a red dot? And "ZipfColl_mean" should be the legend title, not the key label!

Comment: Sure. Not a big deal. See my edited answer.